# Using hurdle control to pass on arguments

Tags: r

Can anyone help with the following problem. I fit the model below using the `pscl` package. I am modelling catch data (about 17,000 entry points) so lots of zero's

```
fit.hurdle.bin = hurdle(Catch ~ Beach + Region + Year+ 
                      Decade + Month + Season + Whale+ Sex + Size+ meantemp + 
                      meanviz + offset(log(Length.nets..km.)), 
                      dist="poisson",zero.dist="binomial",link="logit",trace=T)
```

The model output tells me that:

> Warning message:
>   In sqrt(diag(object$vcov)) : NaNs produced (against year)

I then use hurdle control with “L-BFGS-B” to set some parameter controls to solve this issue, but get the warning message:

```
L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
In addition: Warning message:
In optim(fn = countDist, gr = countGrad, par = c(start$count, if (dist ==  :
  method L-BFGS-B uses 'factr' (and 'pgtol') instead of 'reltol' and 'abstol'
```

How do I write the script for Hurdle control and then integrate hurdle control into hurdle to solve these issues?

Comment: it could help to center and scale the continuous predictors using `scale`.

Answer (score 1):

First, about the initial warning in the `NaN`s in the `$vcov`. I would expect that this is either due to bad scaling in some regressors (as suggested by @agstudy) or by non-identified coefficients.

- The latter case might be caused by some factor levels only being associated with zeros (or only non-zeros) - leading to a lack of variation in the response variable either in the binary hurdle or in the truncated count part of the model.
- The scaling can become an issue if some regressors are huge (in thousands or millions) and other regressors are tiny which may lead to convergence problems and/or near-singularity of the covariance matrix. Using `scale()` on all regressors is one good option. However, often it is alreay sufficient to divide (or multiply) by some appropriate constant, say 1000 or so.

From your description it is hard to say what exactly is going on but I would guess that there is somewhere some lack of identification.

In any case, I think that it is unlikely that changing the optimization method will improve the situation. But concerning the `hurdle.control()` part of the question: The function `hurdle.control()` *always* forces `reltol` to be part of the control list, by default with a smaller value than `optim()`'s default. However, as `method = "L-BFGS-B"` does not use this, it leads to a warning. It does not affect the computations though. With the standard example from `pscl`:

```
library("pscl")
data("bioChemists", package = "pscl")
m1 <- hurdle(art ~ ., data = bioChemists, method = "L-BFGS-B")
## Warning messages:
## 1: In optim(fn = countDist, gr = countGrad, par = c(start$count, if (dist ==  :
## method L-BFGS-B uses 'factr' (and 'pgtol') instead of 'reltol' and 'abstol'
## 2: In optim(fn = zeroDist, gr = zeroGrad, par = c(start$zero, if (zero.dist ==  :
## method L-BFGS-B uses 'factr' (and 'pgtol') instead of 'reltol' and 'abstol'
```

This generates two warning messages (one for each part of the model). If you remove the `reltol` specification manually, the warning disappears:

```
ctrl <- hurdle.control(method = "L-BFGS-B")
ctrl$reltol <- NULL
m2 <- hurdle(art ~ ., data = bioChemists, control = ctrl)
```

But the results are otherwise identical:

```
identical(coef(m1), coef(m2))
## [1] TRUE
identical(vcov(m1), vcov(m2))
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks to the advice from both agstudy and Achim. I used scale(), on all regressors, but this resulted in having no zero's for my response (Catch) and hence  I coudn't run a hurdle model.I re-scaled the regressor Year (1978, 1979....2013,2014) to 1,2.........36,37. All the regressors are now of a similar size and the model works. I am assuming this simple re-scaling of one regressor (Year) is allowed and will not result in an incorrect model?

Comment: Sure. As in any other model with a linear predictor, this just changes the corresponding coefficient and/or the intercept. (Depending on whether you scale with a factor and/or substract a constant.)

Comment: Sex Size
1 1
1 2
2 1
2 2
3 3

Comment: Part of my dataset involves coding for size and sex of shark for each month (this is done over 35 years): 
I have coded 1 for small sharks, 2 for large sharks and 3 for unidentified sex and unident size


Month Sex Size Catch
2 1 1 02 1 2 0
2 2 1 0
2 2 2 0
2 3 3 0
3 1 1 0
3 1 2 0
3 2 1 0
3 2 2 1
3 3 3 0


The hurdle package doesn’t let me put both size and sex as a factor. It only allows me to put one or the other as a factor. If I try both I get “non-finite value supplied by optim”
This I believe is because size and sex are not linearly independent.

Does anyone know how to solve this?